# algorithm: match an user available to join the game to the closest user to him

Tags: algorithm, location, match

my project matches 2 stranger users. so i have a database containing the status of the users and when an user is available for the match, i match him with another stranger user.
I added a function according to which if users shares their location, the user asking for the match is matched with the closest user to him.

Actually, despite i have more than 600 active users per minute, when an user is available for the match, he is matched with the user closest to him, but since there are no other preferences the queue is always made of 2 users, so the closest user to him is the first one still available and not matched.

example: i join the game ( i am available) and waiting for another user. Another user joins the game and he is the closest to me, but just because he is the only one.

i would like to make it more real. i was thinking for example to match users only if the distance is less than 200km, but again the problem is that the user is matched with the first user inside a range of 200km, but maybe 1 second later could have been available other users with a distance lower than the previous user.

example: i join the game, other users joins the game but they are not in the range of 200km. Finally an user joins the game in the range of 200km and he is matched with me, but probably the user coming one second later could have been much more near than me.

how could i make it more real? an idea to develop a better algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would introduce some parameters:

- *match quality*: in your case this just seems to be the distance between the two users, but you could also make it dependent on the waiting time, e.g. by multiplying with a function on elapsed seconds, so that the longer you have to wait the more acceptable are longer distances (with the siginificant disadvantage of having to recalculate distances constantly)
- *quality theshold*: if the match quality between two users is below this threshold they cannot be matched
- *maximum waiting time*: prevents users from waiting too long, if the match quality improves over time then this parameter could be left out (it would be implicitly defined by the maximal distance, the quality formula and the threshold), but the behavior of the queue is more transparent with it
- *minimum waiting time*: allows the queue to fill up (only for the user to be matched, not for the one he is matched with)
- *queue threshold*: if the number of users in the queue is above this threshold, match the first user in the queue immediately ignoring the minimum waiting time
- optional: a second higher threshold for the quality above which users are matched immediately to reduce waiting times a little, so everytime you add a user to the queue you could calculate the match quality with the first one in the queue and match immediately if above the threshold

If your goal is to make it fair/balanced for all the users, then it is probably best to always match the first user in the queue with his best match (when he meets matching conditions). The disadvantage is that someone from a remote area might block the queue for "maximum waiting time". But this seems to be the most feasible way, because users are garanteed to be matched and not waiting forever (what could happen if you always tried to find the best pairings in the queue, not just the best match for the first user in the queue).